# Can't display data from Mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server, pug

I'm following this tutorial: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

When I do `db.usercollection.find().pretty()` in my mongo terminal, my records print - so I know I have records to display.

When I do `http://localhost:3000/userlist` in my browser, I get the words "User List" at the top - but I don't get any of the user data.

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4L7U.png).

**Question: Is my link in my userlist.jade file not pointing to the database data??**

*userlist.jade*

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username
```

*index.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

*app.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// new code
// we want to talk to mongodb, use monk to do it, databasebase is lcoated at localhost:27017/nodetest1
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Make our db accessible to our router - new code 
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});


// telling Express what route files to use 
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

// our master app exporting its app object. All modules export an object whch can easily be called elsewhere in code. 
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. It works fine for me

Comment: In `router.get('/userlist...` inside `collection.find`'s callback try to add `console.log(e, docs);` before res.render to see if any docs are returned or if there's any error.

Comment: @Molda I'm still getting nothing except the word "User List" at the top. No database data is displayed.

Comment: @hagan10 Did you do what i suggested? if so what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same error and then i fixed the problem:

> app.js

var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

> change the localhost to 127.0.0.1

and make sure the collection name is nodetest1